# chkconfig issue in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

This happens `chkconfig --add mysql` command is executed. Have done `ln -s /usr/lib/insserv/insserv /sbin/insserv` but the issue prevails.

```
insserv: warning: script 'K20acpi-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'mysql' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'anacron' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'alsa-mixer-save' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (0 6) of script `umountfs' overwrites defaults (empty).
.
.
.
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (0) of script `halt' overwrites defaults (empty).
insserv: warning: script 'screen-cleanup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'dbus' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'network-manager' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'acpi-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (0 6) of script `sendsigs' overwrites defaults (empty).
insserv: There is a loop between service rsyslog and apache2 if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service apache2 at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service rsyslog at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service apache2 and rsyslog if stopped
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
/sbin/insserv failed, exit code 1
mysql                     0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
```

Little Help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 10.04 `sysv-rc-conf` might be an option. Try install it by:

```
sudo sysv-rc-conf
```

It comes with CLI GUI interface.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/sysv-rc-conf.8.html

Answer (score 0):

`chkconfig` is not native for Ubuntu/Debian, it comes from Redhat/Fedora world.

If you installed MySQL server on Ubuntu using standard mechanism:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

then you don't really need to do anything special to make it work or register it as a service - it would be already registered in the system to be auto-started at boot.

You can still use `service` command for convenience like:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```